# Dynamic Web API Controllers and WithConventionalVerbs()

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm using Dynamic Web API Controllers but my Get methods are being created as POST.
[evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6Zul.png)

I've already set ".WithConventionalVerbs()" but no success

```
Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().DynamicApiControllerBuilder
                .ForAll<IApplicationService>(typeof(AssisteVidaApplicationModule).Assembly, "app")
                .WithConventionalVerbs()
                .Build();
```

My Put and Delete methods are okay.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you could miss; there could be [HttpPost] attribute on PedidoAppService.Get() and PedidoAppService.GetAll() methods. Can you check if there's any HttpPost attribute on these methods? And to understand the problem you can rename the Get method to GetSomething() ... if http verb gets correct we can have more info about the problem.